# How to create a pandas dataframe containing columns with special characters?

Tags: python, pandas, decode, encode

I try to create a Pandas data-frame from a list of dictionaries:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(ls, columns = cols)
```

As a result I get the following error message:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I assume that the errors is caused by the fact that some values of the dictionary contains "special characters" (like `ä` or `ö`).

How can I make pandas to accept these characters?

Comment: Are you using IPython Notebook?

Comment: @Matt, no. I am using a python script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that your default encoding is set to unicode; it is ascii by default. Try

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```